# How do we obtain the probability density of a truncated regression with an upper and lower bound

Tags: regression, probability, distributions, maximum-likelihood, truncation

I know my density for $y$ is supposed to be something of this form $$g(y|x_{i},t)=\frac{f(y|x'\beta, \sigma^{2})}{F(t|x' \beta' \sigma^{2}}$$ where the numerator is the density of the normal distribution and the denominator is the CDF of the normal evaluated at $t$ when $t$ acts as an upper bound. I do not know how to generalize this process when y is bounded below by A and above by B. I started with $$Prob(y<B|y>A, x')$$ $$=\frac{Prob(A<y<B|x')}{Prob(y>A|x')}$$ $$=\frac{\Phi(\frac{B-x'\beta}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{A-x'\beta}{\sigma})}{1-\Phi(\frac{A-x'\beta}{\sigma})}=F_{y>A} (B)$$ and then I differentiated with respect to B and ended with $$f_{y|y>A, x'} (B) = \frac{\phi(\frac{B-x'\beta}{\sigma})}{\sigma \Phi(\frac{x'\beta - A}{\sigma})}$$ I just do not know if this is correct. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is quite simple. If your density is  proportional to a normal between $[A,B]$, then, it must be
$$
g(y|x,t) = \frac{f(y|x'\beta, \sigma^2)}{F(B|x'\beta, \sigma^2)-F(A|x'\beta, \sigma^2)}.
$$
This can be easily found remembering that $\int_{A}^B g(y|x,t) dy $ must be equal to 1. If you write
$$
g(y|x,t) = \frac{f(y|x'\beta, \sigma^2)}{C}
$$
where $C$ is a constant that you want to find, you get
$$
1 = \int_{A}^B g(y|x,t) dy  = \frac{1}{C} \int_{A}^B f(y|x'\beta, \sigma^2) dy = \frac{F(B|x'\beta, \sigma^2)-F(A|x'\beta, \sigma^2)}{C}
$$
and then
$$
C = F(B|x'\beta, \sigma^2)-F(A|x'\beta, \sigma^2)
$$